# How to wait for full Kafka-message batch with Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

When batch-consuming Kafka messages, one can limit the batch size using `max.poll.records`.

In case the consumer is very fast and its commit offset does not lag significantly, this means that most batches will be much smaller. I'd like to only receive "full" batches, i.e., having my consumer function only invoked then the batch size is reached. So I'm looking for something like `min.poll.records`, which does not exist in that form.

Here is a minimal example of what I'm doing:

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaProperties
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener
import org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component

@SpringBootApplication
class Application

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<Application>(*args)
}

@Component
class TestConsumer {
    @Bean
    fun kafkaBatchListenerContainerFactory(kafkaProperties: KafkaProperties): ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> {
        val configs = kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties()
        configs[ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG] = 1000
        val factory = ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String>()
        factory.consumerFactory = DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory(configs)
        factory.isBatchListener = true
        return factory
    }

    @KafkaListener(
        topics = ["myTopic"],
        containerFactory = "kafkaBatchListenerContainerFactory"
    )
    fun batchListen(values: List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>>) {
        println(values.count())
    }
}
```

When started with a bit of consumer lag, it outputs something like:

```
[...]
1000
1000
1000
[...]
1000
1000
1000
256
27
8
9
3
1
1
23
[...]
```

Is there any way (without manually `sleep`-ing in the consumer handler in case of "incomplete" batches) to have the function invoked when one of the following two conditions is met?
- only when at least `n` messages are there
- or at least `m` milliseconds were spend waiting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kafka has no `min.poll.records`; you can approximate it using `fetch.min.bytes` if your records are a similar length. Also see `fetch.max.wait.ms`.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I've seen those settings. Sadly, in my use-case, the record length can vary significantly for some message types.

Comment: Kafka has no mechanism other than this.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot. So I'll go with my [manual-buffering solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59574500/1866775) for now.

Answer (score 1):

Since, as [pointed out nicely by Gary Russel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59566244/1866775), it's currently not possible to do make Kafka do what I was looking for, here is my solution with manual buffering, which achieves the desired behavior:

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy

@SpringBootApplication
class Application

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<Application>(*args)
}

@Component
class TestConsumer {
    @KafkaListener(topics = ["myTopic"])
    fun listen(value: String) {
        addToBuffer(value)
    }

    private val buffer = mutableSetOf<String>()

    @Synchronized
    fun addToBuffer(message: String) {
        buffer.add(message)
        if (buffer.size >= 300) {
            flushBuffer()
        }
    }

    @Synchronized
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 700)
    @PreDestroy
    fun flushBuffer() {
        if (buffer.isEmpty()) {
            return
        }
        val timestamp = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(Date())
        println("$timestamp: ${buffer.count()}")
        buffer.clear()
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
[...]
2020-01-03T07:01:13.032: 300
2020-01-03T07:01:13.041: 300
2020-01-03T07:01:13.078: 300
2020-01-03T07:01:13.133: 300
2020-01-03T07:01:13.143: 300
2020-01-03T07:01:13.188: 300
2020-01-03T07:01:13.197: 300
2020-01-03T07:01:13.321: 300
2020-01-03T07:01:13.352: 300
2020-01-03T07:01:13.359: 300
2020-01-03T07:01:13.399: 300
2020-01-03T07:01:13.407: 300
2020-01-03T07:01:13.533: 300
2020-01-03T07:01:13.571: 300
2020-01-03T07:01:13.580: 300
2020-01-03T07:01:13.607: 300
2020-01-03T07:01:13.611: 300
2020-01-03T07:01:13.632: 300
2020-01-03T07:01:13.682: 300
2020-01-03T07:01:13.687: 300
2020-01-03T07:01:13.708: 300
2020-01-03T07:01:13.712: 300
2020-01-03T07:01:13.738: 300
2020-01-03T07:01:13.880: 300
2020-01-03T07:01:13.884: 300
2020-01-03T07:01:13.911: 300
2020-01-03T07:01:14.301: 300
2020-01-03T07:01:14.714: 300
2020-01-03T07:01:15.029: 300
2020-01-03T07:01:15.459: 300
2020-01-03T07:01:15.888: 300
2020-01-03T07:01:16.359: 300
[...]
```

So we see after catching up with the consumer lag, it provides batches of `300` matching the topic throughput.

Yes, the `@Synchronized` does kill concurrent processing, but in my use-case, this part is far away from being the bottleneck.

Comment: I am concerned implementing this approach because it might lead to kafka re-balancing if the `fixedDelay` for `flushBuffer()` is more than `MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG`

Comment: @VivekSethi Why should this be the case? `flushBuffer` is called every `fixedDelay` milliseconds. But that does not mean, that it blocks the mutex (from the `@Synchronized`), and thus `addToBuffer`, for so long. The runtime (duration) of a `flushBuffer` call is the important thing, which has to be kept small enough, not the calling frequency.

Comment: I assumed you were using manual acks, but that doesn't look like the case here maybe. So now, what if the application quits unexpectedly? What happens to the buffered values? The kafka offset would have already moved ahead as soon as the value was added to buffer. I doubt that `@PreDestroy` can always be relied upon.

Comment: That's right, yes. If the application crashes in a way not caught by `@PreDestroy`, the messages are lost.

Answer (score 0):

As you wait for the batch to complete (accrue to 300), your offset will be committed each time you go back to the listener to fetch. Each time the listener goes back, it would commit the previous batch, though you may not have processed them as you hold them in the buffer.

If there is a failure (a listener crash, for example), then you will loose messages in the buffer. This may not be an issue for your use case, but just wanted to highlight the possibility.

Comment: If there is an attempt to actually answer the question in there, then it is well camouflaged. Please [edit] to rephrase into something more obviously helpful. Answers in the shape of rethoric questions are a risky thing here, they tend to be misunderstood as asking a new question instead of answering the only one which matters on this page.

Comment: I was commenting to the fact that the solution the original author came up with falls short and cannot be used in production as-is. Just to help out folks and as well make the original author realize his or her solution is insufficient at best.

Comment: edited my response, please see if it makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you're right. This type of buffering can lead to messages getting lost. In my use-case, it's not an issue. Your comment is good and valid, but it probably would be better if you post it as a comment to my answer and not as an answer to the question. :)